# Why i can not read angular js input value with jquery?

Tags: angularjs

I'm new in `angularjs` write this code:

```
<ng-input theme='fumi' id='txtEmail' label='پست الکترونیک' icon='icon icon--fumi mdi mdi-select-all' style="font-size:medium;width:40%;"></ng-input>
```

and try to read that value with `jquery` with this way:

```
var EmailPattern = $('#txtEmail').val();
                alert(EmailPattern);
```

but alert show me null value,how can i solve that problem?thanks all.

Comment: ng-input? You aure that exists?

Comment: Can you place a code for your `ng-input` directive?

Comment: Why would you ever need to do this using jQuery? Use `ng-model` on form controls. Note that `<ng-input>` can't have a value, it's not a form control. Show all relevant code

Comment: @charlietfl how can i use that?please post code solution

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms

Comment: Please don't use the `ng-` prefix for custom directives. The `ng-` prefix is reserved for core directives. For more information, see [AngularJS Wiki -- Best Practices](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Best-Practices).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments you should avoid using jquery for getting an input value, by doing so you are breaking all rules of AngularJS.
There is no need for jquery since you can use the `ng-model` directive.

HTML

```
<ng-input theme='fumi' id='txtEmail' ng-model='text_email' label='پست الکترونیک' icon='icon icon--fumi mdi mdi-select-all' style="font-size:medium;width:40%;"></ng-input>
```

In your controller:

```
alert($scope.text_email);
```

Angular will get the scope variable updated whenever you change the input value. Simple like that.

Also keep in mind that Angular binding is two-way. This means that you can change the scope variable and see the change reflecting on the HTML

Comment: Please Wait for test Your Solution.Thanks for answer